# Conver Chart to Image PowerPoint

Tags: vba, image, charts, powerpoint

I am using the solution found here ([Converting PowerPoint charts to images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42761955/converting-powerpoint-charts-to-images)) to convert charts in powerpoint to images.

Solution works perfectly, however when the conversion happens, I'd like for the pictures to "stay" in the same location and dimension as the original chart.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution was quite simple. had to remember the Height and Widht of the shape too.

```
 Copy the shape the clipboard, delete it and then paste it back as a vector image
Private Function ReplaceChart(oSld As Slide, oShp As Shape)
  Dim shpTop As Single
  Dim shpleft As Single
  Dim shpWidth As Single
  Dim shpHeight As Single


  ' Save the chart position
  shpTop = oShp.Top
  shpleft = oShp.Left
  shpWidth = oShp.Width
  shpHeight = oShp.Height

  ' Copy, delete and paste the shape back as a picture
  oShp.Copy
  oShp.Delete
  ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial ppPasteEnhancedMetafile

  ' Get a reference to the new picture which will be the last shape in the shapes collection
  Set oShp = oSld.Shapes(oSld.Shapes.Count)

  ' Restore the chart picture position
  oShp.Top = shpTop
  oShp.Left = shpleft
  oShp.Width = shpWidth
  oShp.Height = shpHeight
```